solve philosopher's dining problem variant
Consider a variant of the philosopher's dining problem: all chopsticks are placed in the middle of the table, and when a philosopher eats, he only needs to take any two chopsticks from it, and then put them back in the middle after eating. One way to avoid deadlocks is to provide sufficient resources. So if there are N philosophers, how many chopsticks do they need to provide to avoid deadlock problems? Why?
my current answer is N+1
I want to know whether there is a solution less than N+1

No, there is no solution with less than N+1, because with any number X of chopsticks with  X <= N, X  philosophers can grab one chopstick but the can't eat. And as they don't give back their allocated resources until they have eaten, you have a deadlock

@Attie no, N+1 are enough to prevent a deadlock. Because with N+1 chopsticks it's guaranteed that at any time at least one of the N philosophers can grab the 2 chopsticks needed for eating. Of course with 2N it will be faster, because every philosopher can start eating immediately.
